# Laravel - How to get a date when some attribute/field had changed to some value?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

For example I have table

```
orders
```

and model

```
Order
```

order have attribute status. Initial status is 'cart', but second status is 'ordered', after that status is 'processed', after that status id 'delivery', after that status is 'canceled' or completed. I will probably have more than 10 statuses.

Is there any a better solution rather than creating datetime attribute/field for each status :

```
cart_at
ordered_at
processed_at
....
```

and then save datetime for each status after is changed ?

I want a package where I can do something like :

```
echo 'Order is cancelled at '. $order->getDateFor('status', 'canceled');
```

Comment: Maybe the [VentureCraft/revisionable](https://github.com/VentureCraft/revisionable) package can help you.

Comment: @Camilo yes, I created a package which extends revisionable and provide many useful methods...see my answer below...

Answer (score 4):

You can have a table name order_events an log there what is going on with your orders with the following fields:

```
id
order_id
event_type_id
details
created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use VentureCraft/revisionable package to track all changes on your model atributes and then use revisionable upgrade package https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-revisionable-upgrade to get date when status was updated :

```
echo 'order is updated to status "canceled" at ' . $order->dateUpdated('status', 'canceled');
```